# Сверстать углы в CSS

Tags: html, css

Помогите сверстать такие углы в CSS.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.block{
    background: #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;    
}
.block .corner{
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 94%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(20deg);
    transform:skewX(20deg);
}

.block:before,
.block:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; right: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;    
}
.block:before{
     top: 0;   
    border-width: 0 25px 25px 0;
    border-color: transparent #f00 transparent transparent;
}
.block:after{
    bottom: 0; 
    border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #f00 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<span class="corner"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь, это вам поможет. [КодПеро](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/bpzroQ?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.example {
  height: 50px;
  background: #c0392b;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25px 25px, 0px 0px, 980px 0px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="25 25,0 0,980 0,100% 100%,0 100%">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: удивительно непонятно. но круто

Comment: @dDevil мы просто "обрезаем" блок по нужным пропорциям. Магия CSS3, без дополнительных элементов.

Comment: @dDevil что, простите?